# Identify specific group content with auth_membership.group_id

Tags: web2py

I can get registered users to view only what they post and not what others post, below is the simple code i used. What i want now is how to get only members of groups to view only what their group members post and not members of other groups:
How can I change my ***postedDetails controller*** to be able to achieve that?

**MODEL**

```
db.define_table('post',
            Field('body', 'text', requires=IS_NOT_EMPTY(), label='What is on your mind'),
            Field('posted_on', 'datetime', default=request.now, readable=False, writable=False),
            Field('posted_by', 'reference auth_user', default=auth.user_id, readable=False, writable=False))
```

**CONTROLLER**

```
@auth.requires_membership('firstGroup')
def index():
    form=SQLFORM(db.post)
    if form.process().accepted:
        response.flash=T('Entered')
    return locals()

@auth.requires_membership('firstGroup')
def postedDetails():
    user=db.auth_user(auth.user_id)
    if not user or not(user.id==auth.user_id): redirect(URL('index'))
    details=db(db.post.posted_by==user.id).select(db.post.ALL)
    return locals()
```

**VIEWS**

***index***

```
{{extend 'layout.html'}}
{{=form}}
{{pass}
```

***postedDetails***

```
{{extend 'layout.html'}}
{{for details in details:}}
Post: {{=details.body}}<br />
Date & Time of Post: {{=details.posted_on}}<br />
Posted By: {{=details.posted_by.first_name}}<br />
{{pass}}
```

Regards:

Mostwanted

Comment: Can users be members of more than one group? Also, if a user changes group or adds/removes a group, should content they previously be generated be viewable by their old group(s) or the new one(s)?

Comment: Users can only be members of one group at a time. If a user changes groups the previous content they generated earlier can only be viewable by their old group where they generated it while they were still members of, the new group can not view it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the group associated with the post must be frozen at the time of post creation, you should add the group to the post record:

In the model file:

```
def get_group():
    groups = auth.user_groups
    if not groups:
        return None
    group_ids = [id for id in groups if not groups[id].startswith('user_')]
    return group_ids[0] if group_ids else None

db.define_table('post',
    Field('body', 'text', requires=IS_NOT_EMPTY(), label='What is on your mind'),
    Field('posted_on', 'datetime', default=request.now, readable=False, writable=False),
    Field('posted_by', 'reference auth_user', default=auth.user_id,
          readable=False, writable=False),
    Field('group', 'reference auth_group', default=get_group()
```

Note, `auth.user_groups` is a dictionary with the IDs of groups the user belongs to as keys and the associated roles as values. It is stored in the session and updated whenever `auth.add_membership` and `auth.del_membership` are called. By default, in addition to any groups you set up, each user will have a personal group that starts with "user_", so the above `get_group` function filters out that group and returns the ID of the remaining group in `auth.user_groups`, using that value as the default for the `db.post.group` field.

Then, in the controller:

```
@auth.requires_membership('firstGroup')
def postedDetails():
    user_group = get_group()
    details = db(db.post.group == user_group).select()
    return locals()
```

As an aside, in your original code:

```
@auth.requires_membership('firstGroup')
def postedDetails():
    user=db.auth_user(auth.user_id)
    if not user or not(user.id==auth.user_id): redirect(URL('index'))
    details=db(db.post.posted_by==user.id).select(db.post.ALL)
    return locals()
```

First, `auth.user_id` is already the ID of the user, so there is no reason to call `db.auth_user(auth.user_id)` just to get the ID. In fact, `auth.user` is the user record from `db.auth_user`, so in general, there is no reason to call `db.auth_user(auth.user_id)`, even if you need other fields in the record.

Second, `auth.requires_membership` also requires login, so the second line of the original function that checks for the user and redirects otherwise is not necessary.

Comment: Wow it worked! The database information viewed was in a grid table, initially i thought it might give me problems considering that SQLFORM.grid is a dictionary and might not accept `db.post.posted_by==user.id` but it didnt give me problems. Thank you Tony

Answer (score -1):

'anygroup' in auth.user_groups.values()
Rturn
True or False